# passing java variable between 2 scripts in the same jsp

Tags: java, jsp, scriptlet

I have this jsp:

```
<% 
String mystr = "";
some java code %>
<div> ... <div>
<% some java code
  mystr += "something";
 %>
```

how can I pass **mystr** to the second script without having a compilation exception?

Comment: What is  the exception you getting ?

Comment: an exception saying that the variable is not defined

Comment: this is all in the same file right? Should work if so.  UNLESS the fist scriptlet is inside an if-statement or loop, and the second scriptlet is NOT inside the same if-statement or loop. Then you'd need to move the declaration `String mystr = "";` above that if/loop.

Comment: @developerwjk urs is the right response

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the string in jsp page.

```
 <%! String mystr = ""; %>
```